# Core Animation, my code fails on the second animation -iOS

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, caanimation

Every time I use *core animation* I get in trouble! Can someone help me with this bug? It has keept me busy for many hours now.

I am animating the bounds and position of a layer. To really change the *model layer*, and not only the *presentation layer*, I have learnt that one should set the position and bound to their final *toValues* before starting the animation.

My code creates a new `CALayer`-object, and then it animates its position from *A* to *B* for the duration of 1s. *This works fine!*

Later, I use the same code snippet to move the layer back to its original position (A), again for the duration of 1s. This does **not** work! The layer does move back, but it happens very *quickly* as the result of the *default animation caused by the code lines that assigns the position and bound to their toValues*.

*I really would like to **understand** what is wrong with my code!* Is it a *typo*? Or have I *misunderstood* core animation (again)?

Here is my code. The first method creates a new `CALayer` object and adds it to the super layer.

```
-(CALayer*) addLayerFromIm:(UIImage*) im{

    CALayer *lay = [CALayer layer];
    lay.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0, 100,100); // default values never used
    lay.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
    lay.contents = (id) im.CGImage;
    lay.zPosition = 0;
    [self.layer addSublayer:lay];
    return lay;  }
```

The following method adds the animation to the layer, and it also changes its position- and bounds properties.

```
-(CALayer*) animateLayer:(CALayer*) lay fromRect:(CGRect)rcFrom toRect:(CGRect)rcTo duration:(float) duration{

    [lay removeAllAnimations];

    lay.position  = rcTo.origin;
    lay.bounds    = CGRectMake( 0,0, rcTo.size.width,rcTo.size.height);

    CABasicAnimation* animP = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animP.fromValue =[NSValue  valueWithCGPoint:rcFrom.origin];
    animP.toValue =  [NSValue  valueWithCGPoint:rcTo.origin];
    animP.fillMode =  kCAFillModeForwards; 
    animP.duration = duration;
    animP.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    animP.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animP.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    [lay addAnimation:animP forKey:nil]; 


    CABasicAnimation* animB = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
    animB.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, rcFrom.size.width, rcFrom.size.height)];
    animB.toValue   = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, rcTo.size.width, rcTo.size.height)];
    animB.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animB.duration = duration;
    animB.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    animB.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    animB.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    [lay addAnimation:animB forKey:nil];

    return lay; }
```

Here is how the layer is created and animated (this works fine)

```
UIImage* imDst = [UIImage imageNamed:@"connectionDst.png"]; 

CALayer *lay = [self animateLayer:[self addLayerFromIm:imDst] fromRect:rcA toRect:rcB duration:1.0];
```

Later on, I try to move back the layer to A.

```
[self animateLayer:lay fromRect:rcB toRect:rcA duration:1.0];
```

But then the default animation kicks in and moves the layer in 0.2s. My question is: What is wrong with my code, or my approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna say, the approach is a little bit weird. This looks like an auto-reversed animation, which could be simply implemented by the `autoreverses` property of `CABasicAnimation`. Or you can try keyframe animation and `animateWithDuration:` function on `UIView`.